# How to Add a Conditional Attribute in a Visual Force form?

Tags: page-layout, visualforce

I have a VisualForce form that includes a phone number input. I want to turn off Autocomplete on this input based on an incoming URL parameter.

This is what I have now:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!phone}" styleclass="phone" id="phone" maxlength="16"  />
```

And I need something like this, I think:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!phone}" styleclass="phone" id="phone" maxlength="16" autocomplete="{!IF($CurrentPage.Parameters.phoneac == 'false'),"off","")}" />
```

But it doesn't seem to work this way. What am I missing?

It might be that autcomplete is not a valid field for VisualForce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, pleased to announce I solved my own question. There were two issues.

1. I had a misplaced ')' in my code. Don't need that extra paren.
2. It's quite true that autocomplete is not valid field for VisualForce. But there's a handy prefix 'html-' that allows many fields to be passed through to the page. That worked to get the autocomplete attribute through.

So the working code is:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!phone}" styleclass="phone" id="phone" maxlength="16"  html-autocomplete="{!IF($CurrentPage.Parameters.phoneac == 'false',"off","on")}" />
```

Thanks for following along.